# How to get the last Table from SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have ten tables in `SQLite` database:

`2016_08_01(10)` 
`2016_08_01(9)` 
`2016_08_01(8)` 
`2016_08_01(7)` 
`2016_08_01(6)` 
`2016_08_01(5)` 
`2016_08_01(4)` 
`2016_08_01(3)` 
`2016_08_01(2)` 
`2016_08_01`

And I use this `query` to get the last table: 
`SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name DESC` 
but the result is:

`2016_08_01(9)` 
`2016_08_01(8)` 
`2016_08_01(7)` 
`2016_08_01(6)` 
`2016_08_01(5)` 
`2016_08_01(4)` 
`2016_08_01(3)` 
`2016_08_01(2)` 
`2016_08_01(10)      //why?` 
 
`2016_08_01`

The query was working for me until table `2016_08_01(9)`

Is there an alternative `query`? or there's something wrong with my `query`?

Comment: `name` is a string and the sorting is alphabetic. The result is correct

Comment: @juergend How to sort the tables so that table `2016_08_01(10)` becomes the last/first one ?

Answer (score 2):

To make this work, build table names like `2016_08_01(0001)` where the `0001` part is guaranteed to have enough characters to fit the largest number of tables you will create.

However, be aware that you're basically defeating the purpose of an SQL database by doing this.  Is there a reason why you can't make this one single table with a `Segment` column (type INT) to distinguish the groups of records?

Comment: Just my name for a column that says "this row is in group 1, this row in group 2", etc.  Not a special kind of column, or anything.

Answer (score 1):

In <kbd>MySQL</kbd>  <sup>Relevant because the question was tagged MySQL along with sqlite</sup>

it can be done in the following way

```
SELECT 
 name
FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type='table' 
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(SUBSTR(name,LOCATE('(',name)+1,(LOCATE(')',name) -
                   LOCATE('(',name)-1)),0)+0 DESC;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c0dbb/1/0)</kbd>

You can convert it to equivalent `sqlite` logic.

Comment: SQL error or missing database (no such function: SUBSTRING)

Comment: I would add that this problem could be avoided in the future by zero-padding the table names so you have 2016_08_01(10), 2016_08_01(09), 2016_08_01(08), etc.

Comment: I got it. The solution works for `MySQL`. I didn't notice the sql lite tag. :(